# How to predict for one single new data point with a linear regression model in Python?

Tags: python

Below is my model:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [2,3,4,5]

import statsmodels.api as sm

x_const = sm.add_constant(x)
model = sm.OLS(y, x_const).fit()
```

Now I have a new data point:

```
newX = 2.5
```

I tried the following code to do the prediction but it's wrong:

```
newX_const = sm.add_constant(newX)

model.predict(newX_const)
```

The error message is below:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /var/folders/04/0q0jxlp12rz6zg_zm3r5dt540000gp/T/ipykernel_93944/3462446387.py
> in 
> ----> 1 model.predict(newX_const)
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py
> in predict(self, exog, transform, *args, **kwargs)    1157
> exog = np.atleast_2d(exog)  # needed in count model shape[1]    1158
> -> 1159         predict_results = self.model.predict(self.params, exog, *args,    1160
> **kwargs)    1161
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py
> in predict(self, params, exog)
> 379             exog = self.exog
> 380
> --> 381         return np.dot(exog, params)
> 382
> 383     def get_distribution(self, params, scale, exog=None, dist_class=None):
>
> <**array_function** internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)
>
> ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (2,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

How to make it right for one single new data point? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Prediction data and model inputs do not share the same dimension.
You can try for example:

```py
model.predict([1, 2])
```

You trained the model on a matrix of shape `(4,2)`:

```py
>>> sm.add_constant(x)
array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 2.],
       [1., 3.],
       [1., 4.]])
```

That's why the model needs an array of shape `(2,)` to make predictions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But is there any way to just predict for one single data point instead of two (i.e., newX = 1 and 2 in your case)?

Comment: Then you need to call fit with a 1 dimension array, like do sm.OLS(y, x).fit() instead of sm.OLS(y, newX_const).fit()